# QToolBar - disable margins

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

When I call `setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))` on `QToolBar`, it leaves margins from all sides, mainly bottom. `setContextMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` does not help. Other toolbars I have are set up in the form of main window and look fine, but this one is supposed to be in `QDockWidget`, so I need to do it programmatically.

Image with comparison:

[image]

When I force the height of the toolbar to 16, the icons crop.
How to the other toolbar exactly the same size and padding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable margins:

```
layoutThatContainsToolBar->setSpacing(0);
```

Comment: whoops, I thought I may have missed something there. Well, I'm glad you figured it out.